# GitLab Runner Fails to Register Due to Self-Signed TLS Certificate

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

I've deployed a GitLab Runner using Helm, but I'm encountering issues related to the TLS certificate. My GitLab instance uses a self-signed certificate, and it seems the runner is unable to skip the verification process. This is causing the registration of the runner to fail.

Here is the log output from the runner:

```
│
│ ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=Ucz-6Xdm status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.labo.bi/api/v4/runners: Post "https://gitlab.labo.bi/api/v4/runners": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: cer │
│ PANIC: Failed to register the runner.                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
│ Registration attempt 30 of 30                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
│ Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=881 revision=8ec04662 version=16.3.0                                                                                                                           │
│ WARNING: Running in user-mode.                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
│ WARNING: The user-mode requires you to manually start builds processing:                                                                                                                                                                   │
│ WARNING: $ gitlab-runner run                                                                                                                                                                                                               │
│ WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│ WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│ Created missing unique system ID                    system_id=r_Mm32Us39x7mz                                                                                                                                                               │
│ WARNING: Couldn't save new system ID on state file. In order to reliably identify this runner in jobs with a known identifier,                                                                                                             │
│ please ensure there is a text file at the location specified in `state_file` with the contents of `system_id`. Example: echo "r_Mm32Us39x7mz" > "/nonexistent/.gitlab-runner/.runner_system_id"                                            │
│   state_file=/nonexistent/.gitlab-runner/.runner_system_id system_id=r_Mm32Us39x7mz                                                                                                                                                        │
│ Merging configuration from template file "/configmaps/config.template.toml"                                                                                                                                                                │
│ WARNING: Support for registration tokens and runner parameters in the 'register' command has been deprecated in GitLab Runner 15.6 and will be replaced with support for authentication tokens. For more information, see https://gitlab.c │
│ ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=Ucz-6Xdm status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.labo.bi/api/v4/runners: Post "https://gitlab.labo.bi/api/v4/runners": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: cer │
│ PANIC: Failed to register the runner.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Gitlab runner values file to specify the secret in order to pass custom certificates for GitLab Runner

```
certsSecretName: <SECRET NAME>
```

Please take a look at Gitlab documentation for how to specify this secret

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html#providing-a-custom-certificate-for-accessing-gitlab

Based on how you have setup your Gitlab self signed certificate you can create a new secret or use an existing secret as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: What happens if the self-signed value changes because it's auto-generated? How can we skip or handle this?